# Is it secure practice to store queue entries in string format in DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have an application which manage multiple queues for hospital. Each queue contains entry by patient_id.

> Question:

1. Should I be worried about this loop as it is not creating issue right now.
2. Is there any effective alternative way to implement this logic?

Thanks in advance and Sitting tight and hoping for some kind of solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR Do not store arrays in database cells.*

The structure you currently have is dangerous exactly for the reason you stated. Things can get lost if at each database call, the entire list string is updated.

This will probably not come as news to you, but you need to break the queue column into its own table with the following columns:

**reference_id**
This is an auto-generated ID per row so that you can update/delete rows by using this reference.

**queue_id**
The ID of the queue per hospital.

**patient_id**
The patient ID.

**datetime**
(optional) The time and date a patient was entered into the queue. Assuming patients are seen in order of data entry, you can add a datetime so that you can sort their order (although this could technically be done using the reference_id also), and in the future you can can do fun analytics stuff with the datetime.

Comment: what if we lock db when data is fetched and unlock when data is updated?

Comment: I mean you can do that. Or prior to updating the record you can check to make sure the record has not been updated while you have been working on it. But these are technical workarounds, not clean solutions. And in the long run, workarounds and hacks like that will bite you in the behind. Because they're messy, and counterintuitive for the next developer.